# React-Bootstrap aligning columns that have different sized form elements

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am constructing a redux-form and it spans 12 columns.

I have some label+textbox's that span 6 columns and some that span 4 columns. The problem I have is that it seems impossible to align those label+textbox's that have 3 on a line with ones that are just two on a line. I tried offset but it only moves them right and not left.

As you can see from the picture its misaligned.

[image]

The ones that span 6 columns are set so that the label has 3 and textbox 9.

The ones that sit 3 abreast including "State" "Suburb" and "Postcode" span 4 columns and are set also to 3 and 9 respectively.

I tried to use offset ie col-sm-offset but this only pushes the label+textbox to the right and not to the left.

How can I position those label+textboxes that sit 3 on a line so that the text boxes line up?

Comment: I think that those may not line up because your 3 on one line are going to be 100%/3 = 33% and using the bootstrap row/col lineup will cause your 3 and 9 to be worth the 33% width. This makes your col-3 and col-9 only worth 33% of the entire width making that col-3 worth less space than your top column which will be using the 50%

Comment: I think your right. Is there anyway to shift it left etc

Comment: From what I'm looking at everything seems to be lined up correctly so I apologize I'm not totally sure what you're looking to do are you able to give an example. :]

Comment: sorry - looking at the Street Line 1 textbox and the State textbox below. I wanted them to be directly under each other

Comment: Okay if you'd like to do that you would need to use col-6 on that and col-6 of the others and the post code will be on a third line. Or you could also do a col-3 and col-3 on the suburb and post code! Or another interesting idea you could set a min-width on the labels so they are always the same size